# How do I create a loop for multiple iteration of linear regression of OLS with dynamic LHS and RHS?

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, least-squares

I have a dataset with multiple columns with variables that I want to check for correlations. My identifier is country code and the remaining are all variables that are to be studied. The goal is to find the top 5/10 linear regressions among all combinations using r square value as comparison attribute. My data looks like:

Country_code | A1 | A2 | A3 |...... | A193

I want to run a simulation that can run lm in loop and have summaries of all combination of attributes in a list so that I can compare their r square value and publish/plot the top 5/10 correlations.
It should run like
For A1:
lm(A1~A2) then lm(A1~A3).....
Next: lm(A2~A3)....

I know I need to put two loops but either the results are not saved because the summary have too many attributes to be pushed into a list, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R loop over linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546726/r-loop-over-linear-regression)

Comment: if you've already constructed two loops (and the answer suggested by @zephryl doesn't help) but are running into trouble, please show us how far you've gotten. You can make a [mcve] using a built-in data set like `mtcars`. Or, you could just use the `cor()` function to compute all of the correlations directly, then square them!

Comment: None of these provide loop functionality with varying LHS and RHS. The idea is simple, I want to check the best rsquare value if I run linear regression permutations in my dataset df.