# R function to extract glm ORs, CIs, p for looped models

Tags: r, function, lapply, glm

I am looking to run the same logistic regression model for a list of variables. Only one of the predictors matter to me and the covariates will all be the same from model to model.  I have been able to run the models but have trouble exporting the results in a useful format.

```
data(mtcars)
d<-mtcars

d$am<-as.factor(d$am)     #three outcome variables
d$gear<-as.factor(d$gear)
d$cyl<-as.factor(d$cyl)
d$vs<-as.factor(d$vs)     #predictor of interest

vars<-c("am","gear","cyl")

glm.func<-function(x) {
  mod<-glm(get(x)~vs+wt+hp, data=d, family="binomial") #the variable of interest is vs
  mod.sum<-(summary(mod))
  mod.exp<-(exp(cbind(OR=coef(mod), confint(mod))))
}

output<-lapply(vars, glm.func)
output
```

I am able to generate the models but 1) need to add the p value and a column for FDR and 2) reduce it to just the predictor of interest, in this case "vs".  I'd like my data o be numeric and to look like this:

```
var     OR             2.50%    97.50%          P
am      4.3759E-02  7.35E-06    4.70E+00    0.2855
gear    5.5834E+00  3.46E-01    1.33E+02    0.2353
cyl     4.2062E-25  0.00E+00    Inf         0.998
```

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71527853/17303805) on how to do this with `broom::tidy()` and `purrr::map_dfr()`. Here's a base R solution, building on your `glm.func()` function:

```
glm.func <- function(x) {
  mod <- glm(get(x) ~ vs + wt + hp, data = d, family = "binomial") 
  mod.sum <- summary(mod)
  mod.exp <- cbind(
    OR = exp(coef(mod)),
    exp(confint(mod)),
    p = mod.sum$coefficients[, "Pr(>|z|)"]
  )
  cbind(var = x, as.data.frame(mod.exp)["vs1", ])
}
vars <- c("am", "gear", "cyl")
output <- lapply(vars, glm.func)
output <- do.call(rbind, output)
rownames(output) <- NULL
output
```

```
   var           OR        2.5 %     97.5 %         p
1   am 4.375911e-02 7.354903e-06   4.704322 0.2854794
2 gear 5.583369e+00 3.458290e-01 132.815557 0.2353346
3  cyl 4.206157e-25 0.000000e+00        Inf 0.9993028
```